# Switch an event delegate

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I am using a video decoder which send a `NewFrame` event every time a frame is built.

Because I need to accomplish some initialization tasks the very first time it runs, I need to use hook this frame event to a `playingStarted` function, then hook it to another one then which is `imageReceived`.

So I have this:

```
Action<byte[]> currentNewFrameDelegate;

MyClass() {
    currentNewFrameDelegate = playingStarted;
    decoder.NewFrame += currentNewFrameDelegate; // when a new frame is received
}

playingStarted(byte[] image) {
    SomeInitializationTasks();
    processImage(image); // Process that image anyway
    currentNewFrameDelegate = imageReceived; // Switch to a normal image processing
}

imageReceived(byte[] image) {
    processImage(image);
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not sound to work that way... The `playingStarted` function still runs every time a `NewFrame` is received.

Because I have several other place where I want to switch this delegate back to `playingStarted`, I dont want to use the -= then += hack to prevent multiple events subscriptions because it makes the code less readable.

How can I switch a event delegate this way ?

---

**Edit:**

This can be achieved this way:

```
decoder.NewFrame += img => currentNewFrameDelegate?.Invoke(img);
```

However, it create a double call every time the event is fired... So I sadly ended up writing this:

```
Action<byte[]> current;
void hookNewFrameEvent(Action<byte[]> x) {
    decoder.NewFrame -= current;
    decoder.NewFrame += x;
    current = x;
}
```

Which stays the most efficient solution in this time critical piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attached the *target* of `currentNewFrameDelegate` to `decoder.NewFrame` event, it does not keep a reference to your delegate then overwriting won't change anything. You can, however, remove the *old* event handler (here I assume that decoder event is synchronous):

```
playingStarted(byte[] image) {
    SomeInitializationTasks();

    processImage(image);
    decoder.NewFrame -= playingStarted;
    decoder.NewFrame += imageReceived;
}
```

Finally drop the `currentNewFrameDelegate` thing also in ctor:

```
MyClass() {
    decoder.NewFrame += playingStarted;
}
```

Note that if, for any reason, you will need to keep track of the frame index then you can use just one event handler:

```
int frameIndex = 0;

playingStarted(byte[] image) {
    if (frameIndex++ == 0)
        SomeInitializationTasks();

    processImage(image);
}
```

Comment: You put me on the right track ! I did this :

`decoder.NewFrame += img => currentNewFrameDelegate?.Invoke(img);`

It works exactly the way I expect :)

Comment: Hmmmm yes, you can add another layer of indirection (not that a delegate call will seriously impact performance). Not sure if it's clear but it definitely works!

Comment: You're right, this creates a double call for this time critical piece of code... It is not a serious impact, but, ugh. I am going to try to encapsulate an horrid -= then += hack in a method then.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use a flag:

```
private bool _isFirstTime = true;

ImageReceived(byte[] image) {
    if(_isFirstTime) {
        playingStarted(image);
        _isFirstTime = false;
    }
    processImage(image);
}
```

Comment: Well, this is sad, but a bool check is certainly more efficient than the hack I did to switch my event delegate...
Thank you.